# "NoErrorObjectAvailable" Script error with LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have pushed my master branch to a scratch org .The app is working perfectly fine in my production.But when I use the same lightning Web component in Scratch org,it is giving "[NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script" error.
What could have caused this.The same web component is working fine in Chrome so i am guessing its not a browser issue.
Please suggest how to debug this.I am new to LWC.

Comment: Please add the relevant code here. This occurs usually because of a null pointer exception.